# Multi-key Indexing on an Entire Array

Tags: mongodb, indexing, multikey

MongoDB's [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/) explain multi-key indexing. Consider this `comment` document.

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId(...)
 "title": "Grocery Quality"
 "comments": [
    { author_id: ObjectId(...)
      date: Date(...)
      text: "Please expand the cheddar selection." },
    { author_id: ObjectId(...)
      date: Date(...)
      text: "Please expand the mustard selection." },
    { author_id: ObjectId(...)
      date: Date(...)
      text: "Please expand the olive selection." }
 ]
}
```

The docs explain that it's possible to index on the `comments.text`, or any `comments`' field. **However, is it possible to index on the `comments` key itself?**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396219/mongodb-multikey-indexing-structure) demonstrates indexing on an array of strings, however, the above `comments` field is an **array of JSON objects**.

Based on Antoine Girbal's [article](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/47178201123/mongodb-indexing-tip-3-too-many-fields-to-index-use), it appears possible to index on an array of JSON objects where each JSON object has a **different** key name. However, it doesn't appear possible where each JSON object in the array shares the same key names.

Example - https://gist.github.com/kman007us/6797422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can [index subdocuments](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#indexes-on-subdocuments) and they can be in a multikey index.  When indexing a whole subdocuments, it will only match when searching against the whole document eg:

```
db.test.find({records: {hair: "brown"}})
```

Searches for `records` that match documents that are exactly `{hair: "brown"}` and it can use the index to find it.

If you want to find any sub documents that have `hair="brown"` and any other fields the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) is needed eg:

```
db.test.find({"records.hair": "brown"})
```

However, there is no index to use for that - so its a full table scan.

Please note: There are limitations on [index size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index%20Key) and whole documents could easily exceed that size.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ross. So, in the first example, I can use a `comments` index to query for `db.test.find({comments : {text : "foo"} })` **only if** the document's comments array contained a single JSON object with `{text:"foo"}` **exactly**. Regarding your latter search that does not use an index, I would then have to create an index on `records.hair` to only search on `hair`. Thanks for pointing out the index size - my documents are big, so it's likely to exceed 1024 bytes.