# How multi key index is done internally in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, nosql

[Multikey](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) is a array field in the Collection. It's easy to index if the field is not an array field. For an example

```
 {
    {
      "message":"msg1",
      "tags":["abc","cde","efr"]
    },
    {
      "message":"msg2",
      "tags":["abc,"efgh","efk"]
    },
    {
      "message":"msg3",
      "tags":["abc,"efgh","efr"]
    }
  }
```

Here tags are multi-key field.  Could some one explain **How multi key index is done internally in  MongoDB in architectural perspective** since there is not enough resources in the internet to explain about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb: Multikey indexing structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396219/mongodb-multikey-indexing-structure)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this explains all which you need to know.
MongoDB internally stores indexes in B-tree structure:
[Btree Diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Btree.png)  [Btree Detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)